# Why is Default.aspx associated class called _Default?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm using a shared file to keep company name, copyright, version, ... in sync between all projects in a solution. This file also contains

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
```

and I need to mark my DLLs as CLS compliant. In asp.net web forms applications the class associated with Default.aspx is called _Default and that is not CLS compliant and generates a warning.

Renaming the class to Default seems OK. Is there any downside? Why is the class called _Default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only get away with `Default` because C# is case-sensitive. `default` is a reserved word.

And the genrator/template adds the extra `_` because ASP.NET can also be used with VB.NET and `Default` (case insensitive) is also reserved in VB.

The standard template names it `Default.ASPX` because that is a 'standard document` in the default configuration of IIS.

Your class name does not really have to match the ASPX file (URL) name, you can call it `class DefaultPage` or something. Just fix the `Inherits="..."` attribute.

Comment: Does VB.NET have an equivalent of `@Default` to handle that case?

Comment: Yes, `[Default]`. It has to be CLS compliant too.

Comment: Didn't know what Default was used for in VB.Net, that's ugly stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The naming of classes is algorithmic. Generally it will base the name on that of the file, and hence `foo.aspx` and `Bar.aspx` will result in `foo` and `Bar` classes.

Since `default` is a C# keyword (case-sensitive) and `Default` is a VB.NET keyword (case-insensitive), the automatic naming uses an underscore to avoid those keywords.

(It's worth noting that CLSCompliance isn't often very important in ASP.NET projects, where there won't be other code written in other .NET languages using the assembly, making this approach to avoiding keywords all the more reasonable.)

There's no harm in changing the name; the name was only given to you as a convenience to stop you having to type that code.

I'd recommend avoiding `Default` partly because you're going to collide with a keyword in VB.NET, but mostly because since you are not an algorithm, you should be able to think of a more meaningful name for what that class (and its associated page) does. That said, I'll admit to often using `DefaultPage` when I can't really think of much beyond "be the default page for that folder" at the time of coding.